# Lost updates on Hibernate using Tx propagation REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I need some help in managing a mess I have just discovered to have created.

I want to implement a soft-locking mechanism in my entities. I don't want to use Hibernate's locking feature because my processes are made of long-running and composite transactions. To say it in short words: I need to mark an entity as `Locked` whilea method runs, so concurrent calls will prevent from running.

So I have defined the *lock* as a timestamp (to be used in the future to detect lock timeouts) column

```
@Column(name="LOCK_TIME")
private Date lockTime;
```

So far so good. Now...

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(Long entityId){

    Object lockInfo = lockManager.acquireLock(entityId);  //@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
    if (lockInfo == null) // e.g. lock not acquired
        throw new ObjectLockedException();

    try{
        Entity e = entityDao.findById(entityId);

        ....
        entityDao.update(e);
    } finally {
        lockManager.unlock(lockInfo); //@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
    }
}
```

And the LockManager implementation

```
@Override
public LockInfo lock(final Class<? extends Lockable> clazz, final Serializable id) throws NotFoundException
{
    try
    {
        return hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<LockInfo>()
        {

            @Override
            public LockInfo doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
            {
                Lockable object = (Lockable) session.load(clazz, id);
                if (object == null)
                    throw new HibernateException(new NotFoundException(clazz, id));

                if (object.getLockTime() != null)
                    return null;

                object.setLockTime(new Date());
                session.update(object);

                return new LockInfo(clazz, id, object.getLockTime());
            }
        });
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.getCause() instanceof NotFoundException)
            throw (NotFoundException) ex.getCause();
        throw ex;
    }
}

@Override
public void unlock(final LockInfo lock) throws NotFoundException, InvalidOperationException, IllegalArgumentException, ObjectNotLockedException
{
    try
    {
        hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<Void>()
        {

            @Override
            public Void doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
            {
                Lockable object = (Lockable) session.load(lock.getClazz(), lock.getId());
                if (object == null)
                    throw new HibernateException(new NotFoundException(lock.getClazz(), lock.getId()));

                if (object.getLockTime() == null || !lock.getLockDate()
                                                         .equals(object.getLockTime()))
                    throw new HibernateException(new ObjectNotLockedException(lock.getId()));

                object.setLockTime(null);
                session.update(object);

                return null;
            }
        });
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.getCause() instanceof NotFoundException)
            throw (NotFoundException) ex.getCause();
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Little debugging revealed me the error I have done: the object remained locked after method execution.

I have thought about it and drawed a state sequence:

```
| Statement                         | value of e |     DB state |
|-----------------------------------|:----------:|-------------:|
| lockManager.acquireLock(entityId) |            |  lock = null |
| e = entityDao.findById(entityId)  |   locked   | lock != null |
| lockManager.unlock                |   locked   |  lock = null |
| commit doSomething                | locked     | lock != null |
```

Basically even if `entityDao.update(e)` is before entity's unlocking (I won't show `lock()` and `unlock()` methods because they are trivial), the actual update **only** occurs after method ends. And since the variable `e` holds its own locking information, not up to date with the database, Hibernate uses it as part of the update. In plain SQL, this would never occur because you wouldn't touch.

I'm discovering I have designed my lock system badly: I would like to ask you how to improve my design considering the following requirements:

1. The locks must be effective ASAP
2. The locks must be removed at any cost at the end of the method (`finally` clause), even if the main transaction rolls back

I was thinking about using a separate table for locks (columns `entityClass` and `entityId`) but I'd like to know if my design pattern (lock column) could be adapted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before posting the question I took a day time to re-examine my design and eventually found the solution by myself. I want to share it for posterity, just in case.

My former analysis (the new transaction being overwritten by the method's transaction) was correct, and is based on the fact that the method's transaction is ultimately committed after the unlock transaction while instead the tx sequence should be: lock, process, unlock.

Two simple code modifications made the thing happen:

1. Make the `lockTime` field immutable using `@Column(updatable=false)`
2. Use HQL to update the locks

This is the final `LockManager` class

```
@Override
public LockInfo lock(final Class<? extends Lockable> clazz, final Serializable id) throws NotFoundException
{
    try
    {
        return hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<LockInfo>()
        {

            @Override
            public LockInfo doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
            {
                Date lockTime = new Date();
                Query q = session.createQuery(String.format("update %1s item set item.lockTime = :lock where item.id = :id and item.lockTime is null", clazz.getSimpleName()))
                                 .setDate("lock", lockTime)
                                 .setParameter("id", id);

                return q.executeUpdate() > 0 ? new LockInfo(clazz, id, lockTime) : null;
            }
        });
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.getCause() instanceof NotFoundException)
            throw (NotFoundException) ex.getCause();
        throw ex;
    }
}

@Override
public void unlock(final LockInfo lock) throws NotFoundException, InvalidOperationException, IllegalArgumentException, ObjectNotLockedException
{
    try
    {
        hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<Void>()
        {

            @Override
            public Void doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
            {
                Query q = session.createQuery(String.format("update %1s item set item.lockTime = null where item.id = :id and item.lockTime = :lock", lock.getClazz()
                                                                                                                                                          .getSimpleName()))
                                 .setDate("lock", lock.getLockDate())
                                 .setParameter("id", lock.getId());

                if (q.executeUpdate() == 1)
                    return null;
                else
                    throw new HibernateException(new ObjectNotLockedException(lock.getId()));
            }
        });
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.getCause() instanceof NotFoundException)
            throw (NotFoundException) ex.getCause();
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

### Rationale

Hibernate automatically excludes columns marked `updatable=false` from updating via `Session`. But won't notice if you run a plain old HQL statement on the unmodifiable field